# identifying phone numbers (different format but same number)

Tags: regex, api

On my website, people can register with their telephone number. Only one account per phone number is allowed. The problem is: a phone number can be written in several ways.

I'm from Belgium. Our (mobile) phone numbers are like this: 04xx xx xx xx (for example 04 99 12 34 56). Belgium's country code is 0032, so 0032499 12 34 56 is also a valid phone number, just like +32499 12 34 56 is.

So no I have three phone numbers which are exactly the same, but are written different and the system does not recognize them as the same.

**Possible solution (will not work)**

Every Belgian phone number has the same ending:

00324xxxxxxxx

+324xxxxxxxx

04xxxxxxxx

I could check the last 9 digits (starting with 4), but the problem is: not only people from Belgium can register, also other countries can register. A US mobile phone number does not end with 4xxxxxxxx, so I could not do this check on these numbers.

**Possible solution**

Adding a dropdown with all the country codes, and normalizing every phone number before it is submitted.

For Belgian phone numbers: +32 (dropdown) 0499 12 34 56 (input) would become +32 (dropdown) 499 12 34 56 (strip the 0).

**Possible solution 2**

I could use an API like this one (https://www.searchbug.com/api/identify-phone-number.aspx) but it's not free. Is there a free solution I can host myself?

Comment: If you want to use a pattern, perhaps this page could get you started https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: Some comment I saved for a question like this: *use [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) on frontend and [libphonenumber-for-php](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php) on backend if you need to sanitize and validate international phone numbers.*

Comment: In which language are you programming your website?

Comment: @PierreFrançois backend is nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your website is implemented in PHP, you can *normalize* your phone numbers before inserting these in your database in the following way:

```
<?php
$input_number="00324xxxxxxxx";
// or v.gr. $input_number="04xxxxxxxx";
$number=$input_number;

$number=preg_replace("/^00/", "+", $number);
$number=preg_replace("/^0/", "+32", $number); // see remark below

echo "input: ", $input_number, ", normalized form: ", $number, "\n";
```

If the numbers in the format 04xxxxxxxx are not supposed to be only Belgian numbers, add a drop down feature to force your users to provide a country prefix.

Comment: Indeed, I think the dropdown feature is the way to go.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the white spaces from the number somewhere in your code.